# Creating a simple oEmbed system in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

For a personal project I'm trying to create a simple oEmbed system using Nodejs.

My route looks like this:

```
app.get('/oembed/:url', function (req, res) {
    oembed.get(req.params.url, function (error, result) {
        return res.json(200, {message: "OK"});
    });
});
```

and oembed is exposed using `var oembed = require('../oembed');`

For the `oembed.js` itself I have:

```
var request = require('request');

exports.get = function(url, callback) {
    //this bit will be developed to call different functions depending on the URL
    html = vimeo(url)

};

function vimeo(url) {
    var videoUrl = url;
    var endpoint = 'http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json';
    var url = endpoint + '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(videoUrl) + '&width=640';

    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var video = JSON.parse(body);
          return video.html
        }
    })

}
```

So far, the `vimeo` function returns the desired html to the function call but I'm a bit lost from here. I'm not sure how I return the html to the initial request (the oembed.get part) and utilise the callback's error and result parameters.

Any help (and advice) would be much appreciated.

Comment: Should you not return a promise? I suspect you are getting "undefined" returned, then you will see in the console that some html is being returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just don't understand how callback functions work. You need something like this in your `oembed.js` file:

```
var request = require('request');

exports.get = function(url, callback) {
    var endpoint = 'http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json';

    request(endpoint + '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&width=640', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            try {
                callback(null, JSON.parse(body).html);
            } catch (error) {
                callback(error);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

And your route should look like this:

```
app.get('/oembed/:url', function (req, res) {
    oembed.get(req.params.url, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            res.json(500, {message: error});
        } else {
            res.json(200, {message: "OK"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: very helpful thanks - I assume there's no problem sticking with my private functions though (e.g. Vimeo) or is there a reason you removed it?

Comment: you're dead right by the way - still trying to get my head around callbacks! ha ha

Comment: I removed it just because your `exports.get()` was only calling it and I added its functional inside the exported function, you can add it back, but preserve the same structure.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I can clearly see how the Callback is working now